# Blank Screen with Blinking Underscore When Trying to Install Ubuntu from USB

Tags: 14.04, boot, usb

### Issue

I am trying to install Ubuntu 14.04 LTS from USB.

However, whenever, I try to boot from my bootable USB it just brings up a blank screen with a blinking underscore and nothing else.

### Details

I have tried using two different USBs, `Sandisk Cruzer 4 GB`, and `PNY 60 GB`. My motherboard is an `MSI H81I`.

I created my install USB using `universal booter` and I also tried `ubooter`. Both my USBs are formatted to FAT32 and boot up fine when I use them on a different computer.

I do not have any operating system installed on this computer, so windows secure boot is not the problem.

Comment: I've found I have more consistent results booting from CD.  There are one or two releases from Ubuntu that I cannot boot most of the time from USB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a mobo that uses an EFI boot, sometimes that only works on certain USB ports.  Also, on one of my machines(ASUS MB) the boot selection provides both an EFI and non-EFI boot option.  You might want try one or the other.  Ubuntu Live USB Boot is pretty robust, so as long as you have a good download (more than likely) it should work with no issues.  I am often surprised how well it works out of the box on very old gear (i.e. 10+ year old Dell XPS laptop)