# Black screen with blinking underscore whilst installing Ubuntu

Tags: boot, grub2, system-installation, 22.04, usb-installation

I am trying to install Ubuntu 22.04.2 onto an old Windows 7 desktop pc, but Im encountering an **error I cannot find a solution to**.

- Searching "blinking underscore" gave a wide range of suggestions. But none of them referenced my specific issue. New ubuntu install onto a windows 7 device getting to GRUB and then encountering blank screen.
- Some referenced issues dont get to the GRUB.
- Some referenced issues are upgrading from other linux installs.

I have tried multiple USB devices - This is the only one that actually boots into the GRUB.
I have tried all USB's on the device.
I cannot try a dvd, as I do not have a dvd burner, dvd-rw disc and the dvd-rw was removed from the device a long time ago.

PC is an Acer Aspire x1301

- Intel Pentium G 620 2.6 GHz
- 3 GB DDR2-SDRAM
- 320 GB DVD-RW Card reader integrated
- NVIDIA® GeForce® 7100 Intel® HD Graphics

I have the iso installed on a USB drive, and have selected the drive to boot from.

When the PC boots, I get taken to GNU GRUB version 2.06, with the following options:
[GRUB Version 2.06](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fi2gd.jpg)

Selecting either of the first two options presents me with a black screen with a blinking underscore, as shown here: [Blinking Underscore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/myRS8.jpg)

Any help or support will be welcome.

Windows 7 is fully up todate.

edit: Referenced search.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Blank Screen with Blinking Underscore When Trying to Install Ubuntu from USB](https://askubuntu.com/questions/705310/blank-screen-with-blinking-underscore-when-trying-to-install-ubuntu-from-usb) There are many more references if you care to check.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)